# Office 365: am I part of farm administrators group?

Tags: 2013, permissions, office-365, central-administration, learning

*Is there a definitive check that I can do to determine if my admin account indeed is a member of the Farm administrators group*?

I'm familiar with SharePoint 2010 but new to SharePoint 2013/Office 365. I'm piloting Office 365 with an admin account. 
Many of the tutorials out there I see start with

> Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a
>   member of the Farm administrators group.

but I'm not familiar with the different permissions and levels in this environment so I'm not confident that just being able to access the SharePoint admin center proves that this account is part of the Farm admin group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPO does not have Farm Admins (at least not for tenant users).  There is a Global Admin, however, that gives a user access to a nerfed version of Central Admin.  To determine you are a Global Admin, you can look at the Suite Bar, and if you can see these Admin links, you are a Global Admin. [image: Admin Links]

Comment: Looks like SPO doesn't have Farm admin access at all. But this answers my question - although Global admin does have access to CA, it's not the same access as a Farm Admin to Ca.