# Office 365: "new app" option missing to add app to App Catalog

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, catalog

Following the MSDN article here:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/use-the-app-catalog-to-make-custom-business-apps-available-for-your-sharepoint-online-environment-HA102772362.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102772716
to add a custom sharepoint app to the App Catalog on a trial admin account of Office 365. The app catalog was automatically set-up (or at least I didn't create it).

Step 2.2 in the article directs me to "In the relevant apps library, click new app". I don't see any option to add a new app. It could be that I'm not seeing it or missing a step.

**What/where do I need to do/go to add a new app by following step 2 from the article?**

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing. The upload document is greyed out along with other options that I would have expected to be available.

[image]

Comment: Apps for SharePoint - This is a library where Apps that can be used in the site collection stays. Administrator or user that is a member of the site Owners or Designers group for the App Catalog site will upload the App in this library. http://www.akruratechnologies.com/2012/08/24/office-365-preview-sharepoint-online-how-to-create-an-app-catalog/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out, here is what worked for me:

The apps library-thing (https://mysitecollection.sharepoint.com/sites/apps) is a separate site in the site collection and therefor has its own set of permissions.

To add an app, make sure the signed-in admin account has access to the apps site.
Go to SharePoint Admin Center > Site collections > highlight https://mysitecollection.sharepoint.com/sites/apps > owners > Manage Administrators > **add the Global Admin account (or whatever your account is to add apps) to the Site Collection Administrators list**

[image: Screenshot how to get to the site collection administers dialog box]

You should now have a line at the top of the apps site that says "New App or drag files here". See screenshot in original post.

Comment: It worked like a charm! :) This is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Elsa

Make sure that you sign in to the Office 365 admin center with your SharePoint Online admin user name and password.

If you still can't see option to add new apps then I would recommend re-creating a App catalog site collection in O365 Admin center.

Comment: Thanks Falak! I am logged in with my admin account (see [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95748/office-365-am-i-part-of-farm-administrators-group) ). In addition to not seeing an option to create a catalog, I don't see an option for removing a catalog. Could this be because this is a tenant version of Central Admin?

Comment: You simply didn't have enough permissions in the tenant, either to create a new site collection or app catalog. This is why I asked you verify your permissions. I'm glad you got the permissions.